# Trying to show a JTable and a JTabbedPane in the same Container

Tags: java, swing, layout, jtable, jtabbedpane

I am trying to make a JFrame for displaying the data that my beta-testers are to send me (this part I have already done), and a JTabbedPane for the charts (for their use). //I am hoping for something that, ignoring stuff like the look-and-feel (and coloring; I was too lazy to color the picture all the way), would look something like this: [image]

. //I would have to use CardLayout for the JComboBox to display a different table and a different JTabbedPane for the newly-selected mode; that means two tables and two JTabbedPanes.

I have tried to make a small (extremely-simplified!) example of this setup, a JFrame with only a (very simple!) JTabbedPane and a small JTable. The example works if I give my JPanel (that houses both components) a BorderLayout, but as soon as I give it a GridLayout (or a GridBagLayout //the very Layout I will end up using), **only the last component displays no matter what I try!** *Why is this?*

If it would help any (it might, given how much of a newbie I am to this), here is the example code:

JPanelLayoutTest.java

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;

import javax.swing.JTable;

public class JPanelLayoutTest extends JFrame {

private JPanel aPanel;
private JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
private JTable someTable;

public JPanelLayoutTest(String title) throws HeadlessException {
    super(title);
    aPanel = setupPanel();
}

private JPanel setupPanel()
{
    GridBagLayout gridBag = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    //making the panel have two columns and one row
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(gridBag);
    //add someTable to top
    someTable = new JTable(new SampleTableModel());
    /*JPanel somePanel = new JPanel();
    somePanel.add(new JScrollPane(someTable));*/
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    gridBag.setConstraints(new JScrollPane(someTable), constraints);
    add(new JScrollPane(someTable));
    //add tabbedPane to bottom
    tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
    tabbedPane.addTab("some component", new JLabel("some text"));
    /*JPanel someOtherPanel = new JPanel();
    someOtherPanel.add(tabbedPane);*/
    constraints.gridy = 1;
    gridBag.setConstraints(tabbedPane, constraints);
    add(tabbedPane);
    //add(tabbedPane);
    return panel;
}

public void turnOnWindow()
{
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
    //setSize(400,200);
    pack();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JPanelLayoutTest frame = new JPanelLayoutTest("JPanel Layout Test");
    frame.turnOnWindow();
}
}
//Pardon the indentation; I wish this forum had support for the [code][/code] tag
```

SampleTableModel.java

```
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class SampleTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

//declaring the static arrays that will be the data for the table
private final String[] columnNames = {"Account", "Full Name", "Balance"};
private final int[] acctNumbers = {1000443749, 190238420, 928355};
private final String[] fullNames = {"Mike Warren", "Jack Smith", "Sarah Brown"};
private final double[] acctBalances = {193.38, 289.28, 21034.29};

public SampleTableModel() 
{
    // I do nothing in here; there is no reason to.
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() { return columnNames.length; }

@Override
public int getRowCount() { return acctNumbers.length; }

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
    switch (column)
    {
        case 0:
            return new Integer(acctNumbers[row]);
        case 1:
            return fullNames[row];
        case 2:
            return new Double(acctBalances[row]);
        default:
            return null;    //there should be no way the code would ever reach here
    }   
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int index) { return columnNames[index]; }
    //Again, forgive my horrible indentation near the end here...
}
```

Comment: btw: the code formatter here can't handle tabs gracefully, better (not only for here) to replace them by spaces

Comment: @kleopatra  Yes it sure does handle tabs OK.  I code in a mix of Netbeans (configured to use spaces) and TextPad (configured to use tabs).  Both work flawlessly on SO.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @AndrewThompson weird, I never seem to be able to format code like the above correctly (didn't try too hard, though) - the outcome after ctrl-k typically is worse than before ..

Comment: @AndrewThompson sorry for having been unclear: while editing code blocks here at SO, ctrl-k un/indents the selected lines

Comment: @kleopatra  Huh.  Ya' learn something new every day.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your Problem

When using a GridBagLayout (and many other layouts), you need to pass the constraints you wish to use for a particular component, otherwise the layout manager will use its default values.

For example, you are doing...

```
gridBag.setConstraints(new JScrollPane(someTable), constraints);
add(new JScrollPane(someTable));
```

But the component you are adding is not the component your applied the constraints to.  Instead, do something more like...

```
add(new JScrollPane(someTable), constraints);
```

### A (possible) better solution

Break your UI down into sections.  Each section has its own unique requirements (I see three sections).

I see a `GridLayout` as the base layout, onto which you want to add three additional panels, which represent three sections of your UI.

This commonly known as compound layouts as you building a series of layouts to produce your final result

Comment: as aside GridBagLayout required to disable column reordering, because reordering can shrink JTables view

Comment: Would the first panel then be compatible with the CardLayout I intend to use to control the contents of the other two panels? `//I drew this GUI with the intent of having the combo box control both the table and the tabbed pane.`

Comment: Also, as for your add(component, constraints) suggestion, I got an IllegalArgumentException on trying that.

Comment: 1- Yes, 2- that's weird, one of the basic contracts of Container is add(Component, Object)

Comment: I know, right? It is telling me that the constraint must either be a String or null. //But then again, I have had some inexplicable things happening to my computer, such as, when I tried your suggestion, for some reason, newlines kept popping up (and I wasn't even hitting the Enter key!) I think I might just try your other solution, but as I said, just add the CardLayout to the JComboBox. `//Though I know how expensive a JPanel really is.`

Comment: I noticed also, that instead of adding to the panel, you're adding your components directly to the frame (which is likely using a BorderLayout) and then passing back an empty panel

Comment: Then in that case I would add the table and tabs to a single panel (using a GridLayout) the add that to a panel which is using CardLayout.  Then this and the combo box panel can be added to the top level (panel or frame) using a GridLayout

Comment: @mKorbel you mean tableColumn column reordering? If so, I can't really understand how that could possibly effect the behaviour of the layoutManager?

Comment: @MadProgrammer Your last suggestion was EXACTLY what I was about to go for! As for your statement of my error, I am such an idiot! Why didn't I notice that earlier?! `//What was I thinking?`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
private JPanel setupPanel()
{
GridBagLayout gridBag = new GridBagLayout();
GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
//making the panel have two columns and one row
JPanel panel = new JPanel(gridBag);
//add someTable to top
someTable = new JTable(new SampleTableModel());
/*JPanel somePanel = new JPanel();
somePanel.add(new JScrollPane(someTable));*/
constraints.gridx = 0;
constraints.gridy = 0;
constraints.gridheight = 1;
constraints.gridwidth = 1;
gridBag.setConstraints(new JScrollPane(someTable), constraints);
add(new JScrollPane(someTable));
//add tabbedPane to bottom
tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
tabbedPane.addTab("some component", new JLabel("some text"));
/*JPanel someOtherPanel = new JPanel();
someOtherPanel.add(tabbedPane);*/
constraints.gridy = 1;
gridBag.setConstraints(tabbedPane, constraints);
add(tabbedPane);
//add(tabbedPane);
return panel;
}
```

I think you will have better luck building your panel as an extention to the JPanel:
EDIT: Forgot to mention that this code is very reusable and allows to to pass in other objects into the JPanel...save you a ton of work as it allows you to overload constructors for different scenarios.

```
//You can call new objects such as:
new MyPanel(data, otherComponent);



public class MyPanel extends JPanel{
    String data;

    public MyPanel(String someData, SomeOtherClass aClass){
    this.data = someData;
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    JPanel panel = new JPanel(gridBag);

    //New addition
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    //add components to the JPanel with your grid (constraints)
    add(new JScrollPane(someTable), constraints)

    //New addition
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 1;
    //add components to the JPanel with your grid (constraints)
    add(tabbedPane , constraints);

    }

    public String getData(){
        return this.data;
    }
}
```

This follows the MVC pattern (which i recommend looking into if you plan on designing more swing). I know it really helped me!

Comment: +1 Just for mentioning using a base panel instead of a JFrame

Comment: no, extending a JSomething without adding (view!) functionality is nearly always a bad idea: JPanel is-a general purpose container, so by adding components you just use its core reason for living, no need to extend

Comment: If he's following MVC than whats the issue? If those objects exist inside the JPanel, he can setup listeners that can indirectly update that panel without any other component "knowing" about it.